# VMWARE ESXi - Untick "Override" programmatically

Tags: vmware, esxi, esx

[image]

This is one of the Networks attached to vSwitch0.
I'd like to untick "Override" as I'd like for it to inherit from the main settings. The thing is I have a few dozens of those and I want to do it via a script. I was not able to find how to do it via ESXCLI. The override occures when you create characteristics for the portgroup, see the following 2 commented out.

```
esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup add --portgroup-name=Grid --vswitch-name=vSwitch0
esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup set --portgroup-name=Grid --vlan-id 123
#esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup policy failover set --portgroup-name=Grid --active-uplinks=vmnic0,vmnic2
#esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup policy failover set --portgroup-name=Grid -l portid
```

I really dont want to re-create everything. There must be a way to untick those boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with powercli:

```
$vs = Get-VirtualSwitch -VMHost $vmhost -Name "vSwitch0"
$nics = (Get-VirtualSwitch -VMHost $vmhost).Nic
$policy1 = Get-VirtualPortgroup -VirtualSwitch $vs -VMHost $vmhost -Name 'net2' | Get-NicTeamingPolicy
$policy1 | Set-NicTeamingPolicy -MakeNicActive $nics[0] -MakeNicStandby $nics[1] # this will set the order
$policy1 | Set-NicTeamingPolicy -InheritFailoverOrder $true # this will uncheck/check the failover inherit tick
```

if doing with esxcli:

first we get current settings (override is not checked)

```
[root@esx:~] esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup policy failover get -p net2
   Load Balancing: srcport
   Network Failure Detection: link
   Notify Switches: true
   Failback: true
   Active Adapters: vmnic5, vmnic4
   Standby Adapters:
   Unused Adapters:
   Override Vswitch Load Balancing: false
   Override Vswitch Network Failure Detection: false
   Override Vswitch Notify Switches: false
   Override Vswitch Failback: false
   Override Vswitch Uplinks: false
```

next we run the command to set the nicorder we would like to have and check again.

```
[root@esx:~] esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup policy failover set -a vmnic5 -s vmnic4 -p net2
[root@esx:~] esxcli network vswitch standard portgroup policy failover get -p net2
   Load Balancing: srcport
   Network Failure Detection: link
   Notify Switches: true
   Failback: true
   Active Adapters: vmnic5
   Standby Adapters: vmnic4
   Unused Adapters:
   Override Vswitch Load Balancing: false
   Override Vswitch Network Failure Detection: false
   Override Vswitch Notify Switches: false
   Override Vswitch Failback: false
   Override Vswitch Uplinks: true
```

this will tick the override checkbox and set the active nic to vmnic5 and stby to vmnic4

Good luck
Pargit

Answer (score 0):

I rigged up a script with PowerCLI.
Cant believe I didnt think of using it...

```
$vmhost = 'server_name'
$portgroups = Get-VirtualPortGroup -VirtualSwitch vSwitch0 -VMHost $vmhost | select -ExpandProperty Name | sort

foreach ( $portgroup in $portgroups ) {

    $portgroup
    Write-Output ""

    $policy1 = Get-VirtualPortGroup -VirtualSwitch vSwitch0 -VMHost $vmhost -Name $portgroup | Get-NicTeamingPolicy

    Write-Output "Load Balancing: "
    $policy1.IsLoadBalancingInherited
    if (!($policy1.IsLoadBalancingInherited)) { $policy1 | Set-NicTeamingPolicy -InheritLoadBalancingPolicy $true }
  
    
    Write-Output "Network Failure Detection: "
    $policy1.IsNetworkFailoverDetectionInherited
    if (!($policy1.IsNetworkFailoverDetectionInherited)) { $policy1 | Set-NicTeamingPolicy -InheritNetworkFailoverDetectionPolicy $true }
        
    Write-Output "Notify Switches: "
    $policy1.IsNotifySwitchesInherited
    if (!($policy1.IsNotifySwitchesInherited)) { $policy1 | Set-NicTeamingPolicy -InheritNotifySwitches $true }
    

    Write-Output "Failback: "
    $policy1.IsFailbackInherited
    if (!($policy1.IsFailbackInherited)) { $policy1 | Set-NicTeamingPolicy -InheritFailback $true }
    
    Write-Output "Failover Order: "
    $policy1.IsFailoverOrderInherited
    if (!($policy1.IsFailoverOrderInherited)) { $policy1 | Set-NicTeamingPolicy -InheritFailoverOrder $true }
    
    
    Write-Output ""
    Write-Output ""
}
```